# I want to align the items in my navbar without the use of Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align my items in navbar without using Bootstrap because I want to build a solid foundation first with CSS. But I can't align my *navbar-right* with my logo and *navbar-center*. I've been trying to find solutions but no one seems to have post this problem yet :( Please help! Thank you in advance! Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="navigation">
    <div class="name">Logo</div>
      <div class="menu-list">
       <!-- Center Nav -->
        <ul class="navbar-center">
          <li><a href="">Sneakers</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Apparel</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Ack</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-list-right">
    <ul class="navbar-right">
    <!-- Right nav -->
      <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Bag</a></li>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navigation {
    background: skyblue;
  }

  .name {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }

  .menu-list ul {
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0;
  }

  .menu-list ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .menu-list ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }


  .menu-list-right ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

 .menu-list-right ul li {
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .menu-list-right ul li a {
   text-decoration: none;
 }

.name, .navbar-center, .navbar-right li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using **[CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**. Make your `.navigation` a flex layout, like:

```
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Horizontally space-out items */
  align-items: center; /* Vertically center align items */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navigation {
    background: skyblue;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .name {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }

.menu-list {
  flex: 3;
}

  .menu-list ul {
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0 10px;
  }

  .menu-list ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .menu-list ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }

.menu-list-right {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu-list-right ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

 .menu-list-right ul li {
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .menu-list-right ul li a {
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 0 5px;
 }

.name, .navbar-center, .navbar-right li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="name">Logo</div>
      <div class="menu-list">
       <!-- Center Nav -->
        <ul class="navbar-center">
          <li><a href="">Sneakers</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Apparel</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Ack</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-list-right">
    <ul class="navbar-right">
    <!-- Right nav -->
      <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Bag</a></li>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!! Exactly what I needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use flexbox :

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.navbar-center, .navbar-right {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;
}
.navbar-center li, .navbar-right li {
  align-self: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set certain `width` for each element then use `display:inline` or `float: left`

```css
 body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navigation {
    background: skyblue;
  }
  
  .navigation::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.name {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}

.menu-list {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.menu-list-right {
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
}

  .menu-list ul {
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0;
  }

  .menu-list ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .menu-list ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }


  .menu-list-right ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

 .menu-list-right ul li {
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .menu-list-right ul li a {
   text-decoration: none;
 }

.name, .navbar-center, .navbar-right li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
<div class="name">Logo</div>
<div class="menu-list">
<!-- Center Nav -->
<ul class="navbar-center">
<li><a href="">Sneakers</a></li>
<li><a href="">Apparel</a></li>
<li><a href="">Ack</a></li>
<li><a href="">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="menu-list-right">
<ul class="navbar-right">
<!-- Right nav -->
<li><a href="">Search</a></li>
<li><a href="">Bag</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```